# Can I customize InputSplit to split based to the end of exception

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I have a big log file which contains a lot of exceptions I want to write a custom input format that gives the exception as the key and the exception text as value, also i want to create custom splits so that every mapper gets all of the exception.

I have tried to create a custom record reader but the problem is that I do not know how to create a custom Get Splits method.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to write a custom input format that gives the exception as the key and the exception text as value

Easy enough - custom record reader.

> also i want to create custom splits so that every mapper gets all of the exception

This isn't how MapReduce generally works.

> but the problem is that I do not know how to create a custom `GetSplits` method

This is done in the `InputFormat` class and there are plenty of examples out there.

Comment: actually i want to create a split by checking the end of the exception and not the end of line , and i have searched the net but i am not able to get the solution, can you please guide me to some links.

Comment: First, you don't want your `getSplits` method to read the data - that is hugely inefficient.  Second, the `RecordReader` has every right to read past a split boundary if it needs to for an entire exception trace.  The issue is when your split starts in the middle of an exception, how would you know?